# What is the Folder being referenced in PYTHONPATH?

Tags: python, macos, pythonpath

I need to add a directory to my PYTHONPATH variable based on directions from a project that state the following:

```
Modify your ~/.bashrc file by adding the following line
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:YourFolder/Dir-Folder/
```

What would YourFolder be in this case if I am using a mac and Dir-Folder is under Mac-HD/Users/username/Dir-Folder?

When I'm in terminal and I run python then run `print(sys.path)`, Dir-Folder doesn't show up. I currently have it set as:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:~/Dir-Folder/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should run `source ~/.bashrc` command in order to make the changes you made in `~/.bashrc` visible immediately.

You can also consider making the change to `~/.bash_profile` instead. Then, you wouldn't have to run the `source` command over and over again. See http://goo.gl/1cxWpq.

Comment: That did it. I assumed it'd be a simple fix like that. Thanks!